# TFS Build Agent: Drop Files in Working Folder

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

i have my TFS with a Build Agent running on my Server.
I want to Copy all files from the Project in the working Folder directly.

My Problem is that the Agent creates a Folder 1/s and put all files in there. But the files should be directly in the Build Agent working Folder.

Have anyone an idea?

Comment: Can you clarify why you want the agent to place the files in the root of the work folder? What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. In order for the agent to be able to handle multiple workspace configurations and to have subfolders for tests, binaries, artefacts and other elements that are created during the build, it creates a unique working folder structure per workspace/git repository.

A lot of tasks in the build workflow make direct use of this structure.

Apart from specifying the root of the working folder (under which these numbered folders are created), it's not possible to specify a different subfolder structure.

You could always use a Copy Files/Move Files task to move the files to a different location as part of the build though.

See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/6c722ba1040089f12322d10239bae0673c8ba54e/docs/jobdirectories.md

Comment: OK but what can i do to reach this solution?

Comment: As I said, what you want is not possible. That's the only answer.

Comment: Is there no other way to release it in the same Folder?

Comment: To work around it you can add a copy files task to your work flow right after the sources have been fetched. That will place the files wherever you want them. Though I strongly recommend against placing them in the root work folder.